# How to get original special characters from SQLite db using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I am inserting HTML content (which has special characters like bullets, etc) into the SQLite database.

When I try to get the content on a view, it does not show the special characters correctly. It shows me junk text.

How can I ensure that whatever text I insert in database, it is displayed correctly on the view.

Thanks!

My Insertion code:

// This query method implementation is in different file

```
- (NSArray *)executeQuery:(NSString *)sql arguments:(NSArray *)args {
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStmt;

    if (![self prepareSql:sql inStatament:(&sqlStmt)])
        return nil;

    int i = 0;
    int queryParamCount = sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(sqlStmt);
    while (i++ < queryParamCount)
        [self bindObject:[args objectAtIndex:(i - 1)] toColumn:i inStatament:sqlStmt];

    NSMutableArray *arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   // By Devang
    int columnCount = sqlite3_column_count(sqlStmt);
    while ([self hasData:sqlStmt]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for (i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
            id columnName = [self columnName:sqlStmt columnIndex:i];
            id columnData = [self columnData:sqlStmt columnIndex:i];
            [dictionary setObject:columnData forKey:columnName];
        }
        [arrayList addObject:dictionary];

        //[arrayList addObject:[dictionary autorelease]];
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStmt);

    return arrayList;
}
```

// now call this method by make object for this file

```
NSString *inserQuery =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into feedtest (title,summary,image,id) values ('%@','%@','%@',%d)",cell.textLabel.text,source,returnURL,indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"query - %@",inserQuery);

    [database executeQuery:inserQuery];
```

// Retrive the data

```
NSString *sd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select title,summary from feedtest"];

    NSMutableArray *p=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    p=[[database executeQuery:sd ] mutableCopy];
    [database close];

    NSString *titleHTML = [[p objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *postHTML =[[p objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"summary"];
    NSLog(@"%@",titleHTML);
    NSLog(@"%@",postHTML);
```

Comment: post your INSERTION and SELECTION code please

Comment: When you NSLog(@"query - %@",inserQuery); Do you see HTML characters on console? I guess you are removing HTML while parsing data received from web

Comment: yes, junk text is shown in console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check your local database using FireFox plugin SQLite. But, sometimes on retrieving we faced strange problem like what is present in the storage not coming properly and sometime, there is crash. So my suggestion is what you should check encoding scheme(normally, it's not matter more) and while getting data use this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)] ;
```

instead of:

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
```

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me. :)